# reduce empty space between 2 texts using css

Tags: css

please visit these links :

1st link : http://site1.com/ellisha-s-world-states-of-india-1.html

2nd link : http://site1.com/ellisha-s-world-science-1.html

search for word "CASH" , under "Cash on delivery" , you can see

1)Available & 2) Not Available.

but there is more empty space between "CASH ON DELIVERY" &  "Not available"

I want to reduce the space as in 1st link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your second link 'CASH ON DELIVERY' in different html tag

change that html tag and inline CSS
You can try this CSS without margin on inline `<h5>` tag

```
.reduce {
clear: both;
float: left;
bottom: 13px;
border-radius: 2px;
color: #666;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 11px;
height: 0px;
line-height: 6px;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

html

```
<h5 style="position:relative;bottom: 11px;">
  CASH ON DELIVERY 
</h5>
```

available link

[image]

not available link

[image]

Comment: instead of margin-bottom: -13px; can you give some code with + px.

Comment: please check here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37545936/display-background-color-for-the-page-align-texts-at-center

Answer (score 2):

```
<h5 style="position:relative;bottom: 13px;margin-bottom: -13px;"> CASH ON DELIVERY </h5>
```

**" Not Available**

**Here, you have unnecessary double quote, just simply remove it. And Your code will work fine.**

Comment: i gave one vote for you  please remove images in answer.

Comment: Hi, i don;t have issue in removing the images. Does this violating this forum? :(

Comment: no, if our senior team mebers saw means it may be a problem for me. if you remove it will be helpfull for me, otherwise thats okay.....

Comment: OK dear !! I am always here to help you guys.

Comment: OK. i will do this. I am always there for you guys. By the way, how to remove pics :(

Comment: please help me here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37545936/display-background-color-for-the-page-align-texts-at-center